# how to query on cassandra table using custom index in select clause

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql, datastax

I have a custom index created by solr on cassandra table

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX custom_index ON table_name (column) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
```

As far as i know, in the select clause of cassandra we can only have primary key in the where clause for select query.

Can I use this custom index in the where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run CQL queries based on your lucene-solr indexes, you have to install DataStax Enterprise 4.6 and use the "solr_query" special column, as described here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCql.html

Comment: thanks a lot. With that i noticed we have to make a query like WHERE solr_query='name: cat name: dog -name:fish'. Is there any other way that i can do where <column_name> = 'XXX'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You can use in where clause partition keys and indexes. But if you want to use indexed columns without partition key, you have to specify ALLOW FILTERING (see exemple below)

```
SELECT * FROM <myColumnFamilly> WHERE <column> > 100 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Of course in this exemple  must be a number type.